# Azure Machine Learning Decision Tree output

Tags: azure, decision-tree, azure-machine-learning-service

Is there any way to get the output of the Boosted Decision Tree module in ML Studio? To analyze the learned tree, like in Weka.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update: visualization of decision trees is available now!  Right-click on the output node of the "Train Model" module and select "Visualize".

My old answer:

*I'm sorry; visualization of decision trees isn't available yet.  (I really want it too!  You can upvote this feature request at http://feedback.azure.com/forums/257792-machine-learning/suggestions/7419469-show-variable-importance-after-experiment-runs, but they are currently working on it.)

Just FYI, you can currently see what the model builds for linear algorithms by right-clicking on the "Train Model" module output node and selecting "Visualize".  It will show the initial parameter values and the feature weights.  But for non-linear algorithms like decision trees, that visibility is still forthcoming.*

Comment: Is there a way to see the Feature Information Gain? The documentation mentions that it should be available: https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/azure/cc98f178-b2ed-44a0-8b35-8d02b266f20b

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I don't know your structure but you should have your dataset and the algorithm going into a train model and put the results of the train model with your other half of the dataset (if you used split) into a score model. You can see the scored label and scored probabilities here when you press visualise

[Your experiment should look a bit like this. Connect the boosted decision tree with the dataset to a train model, you can see the results in  the score model](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FFpdr.png)

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Maybe my question was a little unclear, but I thought about visualization of the learned tree. To go through the layers until the predictions